# Sort pandas pivot table by sum of rows and columns

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have (for example) this DataFrame:

```
 COLUMN1 COLUMN2  VALUE
0    0102    1020      1
1    0102    1220      8
2    0102    1210      2
3    0103    1020      1
4    0103    1210      3
5    0103    1222      8
6    0104    1020      3
7    0104    1120      2
```

(In reailty, it's ~9000 rows long.)

From this, I create the pivot table where indexes are COLUMN1, columns are COLUMN2, and the values are from VALUES, filled by 0 where NaN.

```
COLUMN2  1020  1120  1210  1220  1222
COLUMN1                              
0102        1     0     2     8     0
0103        1     0     3     0     8
0104        3     2     0     0     0
```

I have to sort this pivot by the grand total of rows, then by the grand total of columns.
That would look like this:

```
COLUMN2  1220  1222  1020  1210  1120| (GT)
COLUMN1                              |     HIGHEST
0103        0     8     1     3     0| (12) |
0102        8     0     1     2     0| (11) |
0104        0     0     3     0     2| (5)  V
--------------------------------------
(GT:        8     8     5     5     2)
 HIGHTEST---------------------------->  LOWEST
```

Is there a way to do this?
I have tried creating the pivot by importing the indexes and columns as lists, sorted in the order I would like them to appear, but pandas seems to automatically sort them A-Z when creating the table.

Code for the example:

```
import pandas as pd

exampledata=[['0102','1020',1],['0102','1220',8],['0102','1210',2],
             ['0103','1020',1],['0103','1210',3], ['0103','1222',8],
             ['0104','1020',3],['0104','1120',2]]

df = pd.DataFrame(exampledata,columns=['COLUMN1','COLUMN2','VALUE'])
print(df)
pivot = pd.pivot_table(df,
                       index='COLUMN1',
                       columns='COLUMN2',
                       values='VALUE',
                       aggfunc='sum',
                       fill_value=0)
print(pivot)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`pivot_table` has an option `margin` which is convenient for this case:

```
(df.pivot_table(index='COLUMN1', columns='COLUMN2', values='VALUE',
               aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0, margins=True)   # pivot with margins 
   .sort_values('All', ascending=False)  # sort by row sum
   .drop('All', axis=1)                  # drop column `All`
   .sort_values('All', ascending=False, axis=1) # sort by column sum
   .drop('All')    # drop row `All`
)
```

Output:

```
COLUMN2  1220  1222  1020  1210  1120
COLUMN1                              
103         0     8     1     3     0
102         8     0     1     2     0
104         0     0     3     0     2
```

Comment: nice one , instead of taking a sum, this solution utilizes the margins option which is inbuilt under pivot +1

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, and works like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks, those `axis` parameter helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I will try something like this

```
pivot['sum_cols'] = pivot.sum(axis=1)
pivot = pivot.sort_values('sum_cols' , ascending=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

The index of your pivot table (values from `COLUMN1` and `COLUMN2`) are of type `String`, and sorting of `String` is done from A to Z. Perhaps you should input indexes of `Integer` type, and then the sorting will be done numerically. Considering the [pivot_table documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) Integer type is allowed for `columns` and `index`.

```
df = df.astype('int')
```

Now, your `pivot_table` function outputs a `DataFrame`, which you can sort by index or by columns in the same manner you do with any `DataFrame`.

According to [sort_index documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):
For sorting the index you should do:

```
pivot = pivot.sort_index(ascending=0)
```

For sorting the columns you should do:

```
pivot = pivot.sort_index(axis=1, ascending=0)
```