# Sorting a pivot table with win32com using Python

Tags: python, excel, pivot-table, win32com

I would like to sort an Excel pivot table created by using the win32com module with Python.

As I understood, I should use the function AutoSort() and according to the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotfield.autosort), there are four fields, two of which are optional. Therefore, I am specifying only the "Order" and "Field" fields.

```
AutoSort(Order=1, Field="Tot Converted Amount Due")
```

However, when I run the below line of code, I get an error.

```
    wb.Sheets("pivot_table").PivotTables("pivot_table").PivotFields("Tot Converted Amount Due").AutoSort(Order=1, Field="Tot Converted Amount Due")
```

Error:

```
def AutoSort(self, Order=defaultNamedNotOptArg, Field=defaultNamedNotOptArg, PivotLine=defaultNamedOptArg, CustomSubtotal=defaultNamedOptArg):
---> 44         return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(1514, LCID, 1, (24, 0), ((3, 1), (8, 1), (12, 17), (12, 17)),Order
     45             , Field, PivotLine, CustomSubtotal)
     46 

com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146827284), None)
```

What am I doing wrong?

I would really appreciate any inputs or help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is your case, but you need to pass a row field in the `.PivotFields("""Row field""")`.

Comment: This resolved my issue. Based on the name "Tot Converted Amount Due", it appears that the OP is attempting to sort on a value field; however, sorting by values requires calling AutoSort on the row field(s), passing the value field's name as the Field argument.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried sorting with `ascending=true` instead? As in https://stackoverflow.com/a/60778942/18247317

Comment: Here the reference is not related to pivot table in pandas dataframe. It is related to win32com which uses Excel methods to create Pivot tables in Excel directly.